# ArityException, but all arguments seem to be there

Tags: clojure

Here is my function parameter declaration:

```
(defn insert!
 [db mode {:keys [id paths name engage cost failpage redirect priority]}]
 ...fn body...
```

And a test call from the repl:

```
(insert! (:db system) :update {:id 1 :paths [] :name "blah" :engage 2 
       :cost 3 :failpage "hi" :redirect "meta" :priority 9})
```

This fails with error:
`ArityException Wrong number of args (2) passed to: campaign$insert-BANG-$fn`

I cannot figure this one out; it seems that my call matches the function declaration exactly. Is there something really dumb I am missing?

Comment: Have you modified this function's args and since done a :reload of your namespace ? Might be getting an older version, or you might have accidentally defined it in the wrong namespace

Comment: $fn at the end means it is in an anonymous function. Try adding names to each anonymous function, your stack traces will be more readable `(fn what-this-fn-does [args])`. Sadly this is not compatible with `#()` syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The final `$fn` in `campaign$insert-BANG-$fn`<sup>1</sup> in your `ArityException`'s message indicates that it is an anonymous function created inside `insert!` (with an `fn` form or the `#()` syntax) that is receiving the wrong number of arguments. In general it's possible for such a function to "escape" the enclosing function (the enclosing function can return it as its value or put it inside an Atom somewhere etc.), but here the faulty call will be found somewhere in `insert!`'s body, so you'll need to inspect that.

If the problem was with `insert!` itself, the exception message would mention `campaign$insert_BANG_` instead.

An illustration from the REPL:

```
user=> (defn foo [x] ((fn [x y] (+ x y)) x))
#'user/foo
user=> (foo 1 2)
ArityException Wrong number of args (2) passed to: user$foo  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
user=> (foo 1)
ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: user$foo$fn  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

Note `user$foo` in the first case (calling `foo` with two arguments instead of one) and `user$foo$fn` in the second (the call to `(fn [x y] (+ x y))` with only one argument inside `foo`).

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually I'd expect that to read `_BANG_`.

Comment: This is why it is good to use pseudonymous functions - so the stacktrace will be more useful. `(fn what-the-fn-does [args] ...)`.